# Syntax Error - non keyword arg after keyword arg

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

I'm trying to send a message to users when they click this specific button named 'Register', and to do this I created a label and I'm trying to call that label. However, I'm getting this error 'non keyword arg after keyword arg' when trying to compile the code. The label will appear within the window of the toplevel named 'NewWindow'. I believe this is happening because of the method lambda, are there any other better or working ways to prompt to window they registered? Any help is appreciated.

```
RegistrationButton = Button(NewWindow,
                            text="Register",
                            font=("monaco", 10),
                            width=30,
                            relief="groove",
                            RegisteredSuccessfully.config(text="Registered"),
                            command=lambda: Account_Register(RegistrationUsernameEntry.get(),RegistrationPasswordEntry.get()))
RegisteredSuccessfully = Label(NewWindow,
                           font=("verdana", 10),
                           bg="#a1dbcd")
RegisteredSuccessfully.pack()
```

Comment: Did you try reading the error and fixing the code?

Comment: It's because you have a non keyword arg after keyword arg.  Did you even stop to think about the error message for a moment before posting here?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the use of `lambda`.

Comment: I tried to prompt a window/messagebox, but I got the same error. I don't know what arg actually is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `RegisteredSuccessfully.config(text="Registered")` without keyword.